# Declaring/defining c++ struct in different file - better compile time using gcc 4.8.5?

Tags: c++, struct, hashmap

I currently have a c++ code and a Json file. Json file contains enumerations in 2-D structure, so every outer key in Json has a map as its value i.e {Outer_key : {{Inner_key : Inner_value}, ...}, ...}. C++ code contains overloaded print function which parses the input data, and in the process  of the function call, the code fetches Inner_value using Outer_key and Inner_key. For each call of the c++ main function, around 0~10 Inner_values are retrieved; however, the entire Json file maps about ~20,000 Inner_values.

I am using python to create the c++ code, and am compiling using gcc (CMAKE). I need to keep some kind of enumeration map within the body of c++ so I can run c++ code, get intermediate integer value and pass it into enumerations to finally return the associated string.

Right now, I list-initialize a 2-D unordered_map in the main function of the c++ file. This takes the shortest time among all the other compile-time initializations; however, it still takes 5~10 minutes.

On suggestion I received is to divide the 2-D enumerations into multiple(total number of Outer_keys) 1-D structs, store them in a different file, then 'use' a specific 1-D struct when needed.

Two questions I have here.

1. Even if I divide them up, and put them into different files, doesn't the time to compile remain the same?
2. If the compile time is reduced by splitting up in multiple 1-D structs, what approach should I take in coding this? Should I declare structs in .h then call them in .cpp main()? Should I go ahead and define the structs in additional .cpp file? Should I just typedef enums? Also, within the main function or the print function, how can I initialize only the struct that I need?

```
.cpp file generated using python below:

void overLoadedPrint (Particular_Datatype *data, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>> enumMap) {

   printf("%s", enumMap["SomeKey"][A->member1.innerMember1].c_str());

   //A->member1.innerMember1 returns integer.
   //"SomeKey" is known in python so corresponding key is inputted.
}

int main() {
   std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>> enumMap = {{"A", {{"1", "a"},{"2", "b"}}...}
   //list-initalize enumMap.
   //compile time significantly increases here.
   //info of this map is stored in a single json file.

   overLoadedPrint(someData, enumMap);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the whole `enumMap` known at compile time?

Comment: @KamilCuk  Yes, the whole enumMap is known, and it can be treated as a constant.

Comment: Then why do you use dynamic allocation? Why not store it all in constant data? And why `unordered`? If it's known at compile time, can't you sort it compile time? Just `const char *` for strings, simple `struct EnumMap { const char *key; struct Val { const char *key; const char *val; } val; } enumMap = { ....... }`? And then use `binary_search` to find elements in it. Calling tons of `std::string` constructors slowers compile time, there was a thread about such issue somewhere here. Or maybe use std::string_view and std::array for the elements to keep with c++ objects.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am not familiar with the c++, nor on C or C++ structs. Can you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Even if I divide them up, and put them into different files, doesn't the time to compile remain the same?

Splitting a translation unit into fragments usually *increases* compilation time from scratch.

However, each translation unit can be compiled separately, so if you change only one, then only that file need to be recompiled. Having to compile a fraction of a program is usually much faster than compiling it entirely.

Comment: Does this mean if I simply move the enumMap declaration into enum.h and the definition into enum.cpp and call enumMap in main.cpp, then I can make changes to main.cpp but not wait for enumMap to recompile everytime?

Comment: So  enumMap declaration -> enum.h // enumMap definition w/ extern -> enum.cpp // map_structure enumMap = exeternEnumMap -> main.cpp

Comment: @Mikan Yes. Modifiying only main.cpp means that only main.cpp needs to be recompiled.